# Mounting BitLocked VHDX - BitLocker not compatible with this version of Windows

Tags: windows-10, encryption, bitlocker

I've recovered a VHDX from a formatted SD Card, this image itself was copied across from a failing SD Card. (The process completed with no errors, so I've got no indication that the recovery failed at all)

However, when I try to mount it, I get the following response from Windows 10;

[image: BitLocker Wrong Version]

The PC I'm mounting it on, is the PC that the VHDX was originally created on.

I'm using Windows 10 Insider Preview version 14986.

I've tried the Manage-BDE PowerShell CmdLet, but the recovery key fails... Which is odd... I'm not sure whether BitLocker generates a different recovery key per drive?

Comment: Home or Professional?  If the VHDD was encrypted using on a device that has a TPM module you will need the recovery key

Comment: So, the SD card itself mounts ok... and then when you try to mount the VHDX file it gives this error?

Comment: Professional (I get the same error on two PC's both on Pro)... The SD Card mounts ok, but when I try to mount the vhdx, it then says that that the version of bitlocker is wrong.... Grrrr...

Comment: @Ramhound I've got two recovery keys in my microsoft account... I assume they'd be for the sd card (both are for my Surface Pro 3 which has a TPM module of course)...